# Why does a GAN generate samples from a random prior?

Tags: conditional-probability, prior, gan

I've been reading Goodfellow et. al.'s paper on GANs and also the conditional GAN one by Mirza et. al.

While relatively straight forward, I'm not sure I understand why the prior for the generator is random noise from some distribution (eg. Gaussian). Why can't we create a distribution based on the input space rather than use a random one?

Comment: The adversarial family of distributions can be essentially anything and therefore take advantage of the observed sample.